# SQL Group By with Substr

Tags: sql, group-by, substring

I am trying to group by with substring and I know I cannot use an alias but even like this, it is not producing any results.

```
select 
substr(cd_orig_bic,5,2) cd,
case 
when substr(CD_TXN_TYPE,1,1) = '1' then 'a'
    when substr(CD_TXN_TYPE,1,1) = '2' then 'b'
    else 'OTHER'
  end txn_type,
d_booking,
d_value,
d_execution,
from c.c_t_transaction_queue a join c.c_d_currency b on a.id_currency=b.id_currency
where 
d_effective>=to_date('01.01.2017','DD.MM.YYYY') 
and 
d_effective<=to_date('30.09.2017','DD.MM.YYYY')
and substr(cd_orig_bic,5,2)!='SK'
group by substr(cd_orig_bic,5,2);
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Lots of product specific functions there... And the GROUP BY isn't valid ANSI SQL.

Comment: Hello .. .Oracle SQL Developer

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any aggregation function in your query.

Here is how "group by" works:

```
SELECT sum(column1) -- here is a aggregation function
      ,column2
FROM table
GROUP BY column2 -- here is the column you want to aggregate on
```

The result is the sum of column1 for each value of column 2

You can read [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to group by the data as there is no aggregate function used in the query.

If you want unique values you could have distinct values using distinct keyword.

```
select distinct
substr(cd_orig_bic,5,2) cd,
case 
when substr(CD_TXN_TYPE,1,1) = '1' then 'a'
    when substr(CD_TXN_TYPE,1,1) = '2' then 'b'
    else 'OTHER'
  end txn_type,
d_booking,
d_value,
d_execution,
from c.c_t_transaction_queue a join c.c_d_currency b on a.id_currency=b.id_currency
where 
d_effective>=to_date('01.01.2017','DD.MM.YYYY') 
and 
d_effective<=to_date('30.09.2017','DD.MM.YYYY')
and substr(cd_orig_bic,5,2)!='SK';
```

Also if you want to have aggregate function you could have above query as inner and use group by in the outer query.

```
select cd,txn_type,d_booking,sum(d_value) as value,
d_execution from (select 
    substr(cd_orig_bic,5,2) cd,
    case 
    when substr(CD_TXN_TYPE,1,1) = '1' then 'a'
        when substr(CD_TXN_TYPE,1,1) = '2' then 'b'
        else 'OTHER'
      end txn_type,
    d_booking,
    d_value,
    d_execution,
    from c.c_t_transaction_queue a join c.c_d_currency b on a.id_currency=b.id_currency
    where 
    d_effective>=to_date('01.01.2017','DD.MM.YYYY') 
    and 
    d_effective<=to_date('30.09.2017','DD.MM.YYYY')
    and substr(cd_orig_bic,5,2)!='SK'
) group by cd,txn_type,d_booking,d_execution;
```

Comment: Hi, I need to group by the "cd" as it is a country code that goes on repeatedly for several thousand lines

Comment: There is no need to use group by unless you have any aggregate function.Since the purpose of “group by” is to group records when you are using an aggregate function. Please describe your requirement more to understand your query.

Comment: Hi, I need the group by for the cd (country code) as there are way too many more results than country codes

Comment: Yes I understand. but group by doesn't work like this. Tell me one thing : for different country codes does these columns txn_type,d_booking,d_value,d_execution always have same value ?  If you just want to show all same country code one after another without aggregating then use order by cd instead of group by.